# Clear all records from a table on every 10 seconds

Tags: mysqli

I wish to delete all records in a table on every 10 seconds time interval. I had seen similar queries, but it is not working for me.Here i tried a query

```
CREATE EVENT DO_DELETE_OP
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 10 SECOND
DO DELETE FROM tblnew ;
```

where `tblnew` is my tablename. Please help me

Comment: Are You using sql server, right?

Comment: @bigwolk mysqli is tagged which suggest the OP uses mysql/Mariadb

Comment: Looks like the query is constructed correctly; what errors are you getting?

Comment: ya..i am using mysql.

Comment: If safe mode is enabled it won't let you delete or update without specifying the primary key. But it's hard to tell without any error messages.

Comment: tblnew is not clear after 10 seconds

Comment: Please, provide the full code and the error message if exists.

Comment: <?php
mysqli_query("CREATE EVENT DO_DELETE_OP
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 2 SECOND
DO DELETE FROM tblnew");
?>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine .In order for this to **work**, you will need to enable the mysql scheduler, which can be done like this:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Comment: I changed my code to <?php
mysqli_query("CREATE EVENT DO_DELETE_OP
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 2 SECOND
DO DELETE FROM tblnew SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON");
?> But tblnew is not clear.

Comment: In my DB Event Schedular status is off. When i tried to change there shows  Acees denied you need at least one of super privileges

Comment: You can add super privilege using phpmyadmin:
Go to PHPMYADMIN > privileges > Edit User > Under Administrator tab Click SUPER. > Go

Comment: You can check the event scheduler status by SHOW VARIABLES
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler'